# Drill Join between 2 tables on 'Like' Operator returns UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION

Tags: hadoop, apache-drill, mapr

I am trying to run one simple query on Apache Drill:

```
select OTT.Handset, OTT.Handset_OS from datasource.`./OTT_DETAILS_V` as OTT,  datasource.`./OS` as D 
where OTT.Handset_OS like concat('%', D.OS , '%');
```

The above query tries to get all handsets which has instring of OS from ./OS table. This query works on Oracle but on Drill it fails with below error.

```
Error: UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION ERROR: This query cannot be planned possibly due to either a cartesian join or an inequality join
[Error Id: 6f685286-1b79-4083-8a31-a31788c3c403 on cluster-3:31010] (state=,code=0)
```

I think this is bug in Drill. Is there any way we can join between 2 tables for 'Like' Operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that join in Drill (and many other databases) needs to have an exact match condition and can have additional `like` condition. Having `like` condition alone will throw the above error.